# Casting a class type as its known super class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, introspection

I have a parent class in which I would like to use a class variable with a known super class. Is there a way to tell the compiler what the super class is of a type?

My use case is much more complex using an external library (which is why I have to do such a strange thing. Here it is simplified:

```
@interface A
 +(void)MagicMethod;
@end


#import "A.h"
@interface B: A

@end


#import "A.h"
@interface C
{
    Class class_to_call
}

@implementation C
-(void) fun_method
{
   [class_to_call MagicMethod];  // I need some context here to say the base is class A!!!!
}
@end




#import "C.h"
@interface D: C
@end

@implementation D
-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   class_to_call = [B Class];
}
```

As you can see above, there is no way to give context to the class i'm using to call. Is there syntax to say that this "Class" variable holds a class with base type A?

Comment: If all else fails: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it through the Obj-C runtime, but I was hoping to find a casting method so that it read better and still had autocomplete functionality.

Comment: So `MagicMethod` is a class method, not an instance method?  And you want to call using a class pointer rather than a class literal?  (Calling with an instance is easy, so long as the compiler can find the method name to get the parms and return type -- you just cast the instance pointer to `id`.)

Comment: I've done calling of a class method with a class pointer, but it's not an everyday thing, and I don't have the code at hand to look at.

Comment: Yes, it is a class method on a generic Class variable. Trying the code more in XCode, it seems to let you use any selector which it knows of in scope, and then assumes it is that class. This will compile, but I'd prefer to cast explicitly for clarity if there is syntax for it.

Comment: I suggest that you put in an assert that `[class_to_call isSubclassOfClass:[A class]]`. It documents the intent and even enforces it, which a cast would not do.

Comment: @KenThomases - I assign them on object initialization, so this would be a good thing to do in the base class to ensure whoever is implementing the child has understood it.

Comment: All casting would do at this point is effectively "comment" the code.  That can be just as well done with actual comments or with appropriately named variables.

Comment: @HotLicks - I would prefer that the compiler throw a warning on a non-existent method instead of a run-time error.